# Will adding more memory slices increase the overall memory bandwidth?

Tags: performance, hardware, cpu-architecture

Let's say I have a PC with 2 (DDR) memory slices installed, each with a memory speed of 200MHz. According to [the equation here](https://superuser.com/questions/736381/what-does-the-mhz-of-ram-really-mean), each has a bandwidth of 3200MB/s.

Now my question is, if my computer has a memory bandwidth of 3200MB/s, or 6400MB/s?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Note that a single DDR memory channel has a 64-bit data bus (+8 if ECC is supported) and typically multiple DIMMs can be installed on the same channel. The 3200MB/s is the maximum theoretical bandwidth (MTB) of the DIMM in your example. Let's assume for the sake of argument that the memory controller of the CPU (or motherboard in case of an external memory controller) supports 3200MB/s DIMMs. If there is a single 3200MB/s DIMM in the channel, then the MTB of the channel is 3200MB/s as well. If that is the only DIMM connected to the CPU, then the MTB of the CPU is 3200MB/s.

Now if another identical DIMM is installed in the same channel, the MTB of the channel and the CPU remain 3200MB/s because all control and data singles of the channel are shared by all the DIMMs (the memory controller can send a command to one DIMM at a time). However, if an identical DIMM is installed on another channel connected to the same CPU, the MTB of the CPU doubles (the sum of the TMBs of each channel). For example, a [Skylake Xeon Gold/Platinum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)) CPU can support an outstanding MTB of 128 GB/s when each of the 6 channels is populated with at least one 21.33 GB/s DDR4 DIMM (21.33 * 6 = 128).

(In case you're curious, installing DIMMs of different speeds in the same channel makes the channel operate at the speed of the slowest DIMM.)

In practice, the effective memory bandwidth (EMB) is usually much smaller than the MTB of the channel. Installing more DIMMs (identical or even otherwise) in the same channel provides more opportunity for parallelism due to interleaving the physical address space (which is configurable in Intel chipsets), which may increase the EMB of that channel (in contrast to the MTB), but it can never exceed the MTB of course. In fact, one of the benefits of having multiple DIMMs in the same channel is increasing the EMB. Having multiple channels increases the MTB and potentially the EMB at the cost of significant hardware overhead in the CPU/motherboard or SoC.